How to classify orbits of $D_4$?
I have the group $D_4$ acting on a set which has about a few thousand elements. (It is $\{ (a, b, c, d) \mid a, b, c, d \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4\} \}$ with some extra structure which further multiplies the number of elements, where it acts by permutation, i.e. in my case $ (a, b, c, d) = (c, d, a, b)$ and $ (a, b, c, d) = (b, d, a, c)$).
Since $D_4$ is generated by $$ and $$, you get the action of the other group elements from that, e.g. $δ^2(a,b,c,d)=(b,d,a,c)=(d,c,b,a).$.
This is a valid action of the dihedral group since $σδσ(a,b,c,d) = σδ(c,d,a,b) = σ(d,b,c,a) = (c,a,d,b)$ and $δ^3 (a,b,c,d)=δ^2 (b,d,a,c)=(c,a,d,b)$ so $σδσ = δ^3 = δ^{-1}$ and also $σδ^2 σ(a,b,c,d)=σδ^2 (c,d,a,b)=σ(b,a,d,c)=δ^2(a,b,c,d)$, so $σδ^2 σ= δ^2=(δ^2)^{-1}$.
I want to classify all the orbits of $D_4$ on this set. That is, I want for example to write the set of all orbits as a disjoint union of sets, where for each set I can explicitly state the form of the elements in the orbit (or one representant and the subgroup which generates the orbit).
My feeling tells me, that it has something to do with the stabilizers of the orbit, i.e. the subgroups of $D_4$ that leave the orbit invariant, but I can not quite get it and may very well be wrong. (One idea was, that the subgroup which generates the orbit is just the whole group modulo the stabilizer, (which would not yet lead to the classification but may help) but for example if the stabilizer is $\{e, \}$ then it is not normal and thus taking the group modulo that does not make sense.)

I'd stick it in GAP.

It's not clear to me what the action is.

What do you mean by GAP? What exactly is unclear about the action? $D_4=⟨, ⟩$ and I wrote in the question $ (a,b,c,d) = (c, d, a, b)$ and $ (a, b, c, d) = (b, d, a, c)$. From that you can infer, that e.g. $² (a, b, c, d) =  (b, d, a, c) = (d, c, b, a)$. This is a valid action of the dihedral group since $ (a, b, c, d) =  (c, d, a, b) =  (d, b, c, a) = (c, a, d, b)$ and $³ (a, b, c, d) = ² (b, d, a, c) = (c, a, d, b)$ so $=³=⁻¹$ and also $²(a, b, c, d)= ²(c, d, a, b) =  (b, a, d, c) =  ² (a, b, c, d)$, so $²=²= (²)⁻¹$.

https://www.gap-system.org/

Use $x^2$ for $x^2$.

I suggest you [edit] the question to include those details.

I added the details. (and used $x^2$ )Thanks for suggesting gap. That may be my last resort, as I would need to learn it first. But I hope to find a more generally usable analytical method. Maybe a connection between the orbits-classes and subgroups of $D_4$ or something like that.

I found a way to classify the orbits thanks to the hint orbit-stabilizer theorem of one answer, so I will quickly share the main idea.
The more general version of the orbit stabilizer theorem says that
$$ ∀x∈X: : G/G_x → G⋅x \quad g G_x ↦ gx, $$
(where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$ and $G⋅x$ is the orbit,) is a bijection. So if two $x∈X$ share the same stabilizer, there is a bijection between them, so they are in some way the same.
Also if $y=gx$ then $G_y=g G_x g^{-1}$, so if two elements are in the same orbit, their stabilizers are conjugate to each other.
Therefore we can classify the orbits as follows:

Find all subgroups of $G$, as they are all the possible stabilizers.
For each subgroup, find the set of points in $X$ that have this subgroup as a stabilizer. This is a partition of $X$.
Check which subgroups are conjugate to each other.
All the orbits which have stabilizers which are conjugate to each other, are in some way the same type, have the same class.

Therefore we have classified the orbits of an arbitrarily large set in a number of classes which only depends on the number of subgroups of the group.

I'm not entirely sure whether it is what you are looking for, but there is something called the "orbit-stabilizer theorem", it says:
Let $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$ and let $x\in X$ be an element, then $$|G\cdot x|=|G|/|Stab_G(x)|.$$
I think it could be helpful to give your set a bit more structure:  Consider the set as $\mathbb{F}_4^4$, then the action of $D_4$ can be viewed as a multiplication with certain permutation matrices, which are linear maps.
I think that you now can obtain the general form of elements in the following way:
As an example we take $\sigma(a,b,c,d)=(c,d,a,b)$, then $$f(a,b,c,d):=(a,b,c,d)+\sigma(a,b,c,d)=(a,b,c,d)+(c,d,a,b)$$ is a linear map whos kernel is exactly the set of all elements containing $\sigma$ in their stabilizer. Since $$f(a,b,c,d)=(a+c,b+d,a+c,b+d)$$ we get that these elements have to have the form $a=c$ and $b=d$.
I hope that I didn't make any mistakes when going from the original set to $\mathbb{F}_4^4$.
PS: The situation here would've been a lot simpler if $|D_4|$ wouldn't be divisible by 2.

This wasn't quite what I was looking for, but your mention of the orbit-stabilizer theorem helped me in coming up with the solution, so thank you!
